# TestContainers - OracleContainer - how to pass parameters to my sql files by using withCopyFileToContainer

Tags: testcontainers

I'm copying to container my SQL directory that contains multiple sql files, the container wil execute them by alphabetical order. But i should pass parameters (schema_name) to my sql files $1

```
 oracleContainer.withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("database/scripts/"), "/container-entrypoint-startdb.d/")
```

How can i pass parameter to the container to execute correcty the sql files and let it executes like this @ddl.sql &1 ?

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

`withCopyFileToContainer` does nothing more than copying the files to the location you define, it is nearly equivalent to using `docker cp`. The [gvenzl/oracle-xe](https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe)
 supports executing shell scripts rather than SQL scripts as well, so you can use shell scripts if you need more sophisticated behavior.